# insert dates to SQLite 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am planning to have an 'remind me on date' feature on my application. Hence I would want to receive the date from the user and store in SQLite.

What is the easiest way to do this? Should i use the `UIDatePicker`? If so, can you give me an hint of how to do it?

Is it simpler to use 3 picker views for year, month and date and store in SQLite?

Sorry if my question is a bit vague. I am new to iPhone development. I will be very thankful if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the date from the user, certainly use UIDatePicker.

For saving it, first consider using Core Data instead of sqlite directly. But if you insist, the easiest would probably be to convert the NSDate to a double using `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` for storage, and use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:...]` to get back the NSDate when loading from the database.

Comment: I will try it out.. 
How do i store double value in sqlite ? Does it support ?

Comment: It supports a "REAL" data type.

Comment: Assuming one does not need the milliseconds, then the Double could be converted to an Int64 first. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

save date in string format.

Pick date from datePicker and conver into string and save it in db when you need this date you can again convert it into NSDate object.

see this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
    NSString *dateString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           [df stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]];
```

save dateString in database.